# Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow' for add-in within message inspector

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin, office-js, outlook-web-addins

I'm working on an add-in for Outlook which redirects to another URL after authentication. The redirect works fine when running the add-in from the message list viewer. However, if I open a message in an inspector and run the add-in the redirect displays this error:

> Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow': The target origin
>   provided ('https://login.aaa.com') does not match the recipient
>   window's origin ('https://login-uk.aaa.com').

[image]

The URL for the message list viewer is https://remote.aaa.com/owa/#path=/mail

The URL for the inspector is https://remote.aaa.com/owa/projection.aspx

Edit: Investigating this further, it appears that initialising OfficeJS fails after redirecting. The call to Office.onReady() just hangs and doesn't return (I'm using `await Office.onReady()`). I tested this running a test add-in locally which redirected to my add-in running locally and calling Office.onReady() does not do anything and just hangs at that call.

**So URL redirection works but then the add-in doesn't initialise.**

Comment: What client are you experiencing this on? (OWA, Windows Desktop client, Mac, etc.)

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT - OWA

Comment: Have you added all the domains in <AppDomains> section in the manifest. Also did you call office.initialize() before Office.onReady()?

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT Yes, I have added the domains. The add-in does not call `office.initialize()`. I did add it to the test add-in but got the same problem. However, as I mention in the question, the add-in redirect works fine when it is run in the message list view.

Comment: Can you please share the sample code so that we can reproduce the issue.

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT It's easy enough to replicate the problem. Create a basic add-in with a button which when clicked redirects to a different URL. Make sure to add the redirect URL to <AppDomains>. It should redirect okay in the message list view but not when viewing the message in the inspector.

Comment: By redirecting are you talking about opening a new browser window and redirecting to the target page, If yes, i tried this and this works fine in both message list view and inspector view.

Comment: Also if you mean redirecting the current add-in page to a new target page that also works in both the views.

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT I mean redirecting the contents of the task pane to a different URL (i.e. redirecting the current add-in page to a new target page). Did it work for you within the message inspector where the URL of  the message inspector ends with **projection.aspx**? That is the specific problem.

Comment: yes it worked for message inspector where the URL of the message inspector ends with projection.aspx, in the click functionality I used window.location.href = "TargetPageUrl", will be good to know what you are trying for redirection.

Comment: Is the URL you are redirecting to an office add-in web app? Sorry, I made a mistake in a comment above. It is not that the redirection isn't working, it is the fact that `Office.onReady()` in the redirected URL (i.e. URL of an add-in web app) doesn't get called _after_ redirection.

Comment: To clarify on this: Are you trying to redirect to a url of the same add-in web app? If yes, then Office.onReady() should not be called. Or Are you trying to redirect to a different web app?

Comment: It is redirecting to the same web app but at a different URL. For example, the add-in initially points to **www.login.company.com**. The web app is hosted there. Then after authentication it will need to redirect to **www.login-uk.company.com** where the same web app is hosted. I mimicked this by running two simple add-in web apps on localhost one different ports and tried to redirect from on to the other and had the same problem.

Comment: If you are redirecting to the same web app but a different URL, then Office.onReady() should not be called as it is the same add-in.

Comment: I think we may be misunderstanding each other. When I redirect within the task pane the web app I'm redirecting to must call Office.onReady() so that it can retrieve Office.context, etc. This works perfectly fine when redirecting from the message list view.

Comment: To redirect to the same web app, different URL are you using window.location.href = "TargetPageUrl"? How are you calling Office.onReady while redirecting? Code Snippet will really help us here.

Comment: Yes, if you take the example in the comment, for the redirect I am doing `window.location.href = "www.login-uk.company.com"`. The manifest file has www.login-uk.company.com in the <AppDomains> section. The entry point for the add-in is www.login.company.com. The code snippet would simply be an add-in which calls Office.onReady() and also has a button that triggers the redirect. After the redirect we are seeing the Office.onReady() either does not return a value or hangs if using `await Office.onReady()`.

Comment: This is only happening when the message inspector URL contains projection.aspx. So the redirect is fine when running the add-in from the message list view _or_ with an account where the inspector URL _does not_ contain projection.aspx, e.g. office365 accounts. It only occurs in Chrome and Firefox. The account for which the problem occurs does not have projection.aspx in the message inspector URL when using IE.

Comment: Can you please provide a sample code to test this scenario?